# How is Unity's GetComponent implemented in C#

Tags: unity, c#

I'm just curious that what aspects of the C# language Unity's `GetComponent` method uses.

In the C# language we have reflection that lets programmers access a variable by its type. Is `GetComponent` just some type of reflection C# for certain Unity defined types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Various users have decompiled the Unity engine to peek at how it works inside](https://github.com/jameslinden/unity-decompiled), but when you get to the core methods, they tend to just be wrappers calling into native code compiled from C++, rather than being implemented in C# at all.

```
/// <summary>
///   <para>Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">The type of Component to retrieve.</param>
[WrapperlessIcall]
[TypeInferenceRule(TypeInferenceRules.TypeReferencedByFirstArgument)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public Component GetComponent(System.Type type);

[WrapperlessIcall]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal void GetComponentFastPath(System.Type type, IntPtr oneFurtherThanResultValue);

[SecuritySafeCritical]
public unsafe T GetComponent<T>()
{
  CastHelper<T> castHelper = new CastHelper<T>();
  this.GetComponentFastPath(typeof (T), new IntPtr((void*) &castHelper.onePointerFurtherThanT));
  return castHelper.t;
}
```

And the `CastHelper` referenced above is just this struct:

```
internal struct CastHelper<T>
{
  public T t;
  public IntPtr onePointerFurtherThanT;
}
```

It appears to use the fact that `onePointerFurtherThanT` comes immediately after `t` in the struct definition to find the address of the reference `t`, so that the native code called in `GetComponentFastPath` can write the appropriate reference in place to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The sourcecode for the implementation of GetComponent isn't available, so we can only guess how it is actually implemented. So I can only say how **I** would implement this.

You can get the class of an object at runtime using the method [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Object`. When an object got multiple components and the caller wants to get the component of a specific type, there are two ways to do this:

1. Each time `GetComponent` is called, iterate all components of the entity until you find one where `component.GetType() == requestedType`
2. Keep a [`Dictionary<Type, Component> components`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) in each entity. When `GetComponent` is called, look it up in the dictionary.

The first method would be faster when there are only very few components on each entity while the latter would be faster if you have many.

Comment: Note that for some components a game object can have multiple instances attached at once, so you'd want your dictionary to either point to/into a list of components, or do a search-on-remove to see if there's another one the dictionary should reference instead.

Comment: Don't forget to handle superclass calls! `GetComponent<Component>()` is valid and will return a result. As will *interfaces!* e.g. `GetComponent<ISomeInterface>()` will return an object `SomeObject : Component, ISomeInterface`